# How much does it cost to copy files/folders with the same s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have been searching this but only find relevant answers for copy between different buckets. I checked AWS official page for replication charge while it only mentions cross-region and same-region replication, which should be related to inter-bucket replication. Is there any additional charge other than storage for duplicating files/folders within the same bucket?

Comment: If it’s just in the same bucket, you will pay for the requests for doing the copies (e.g. `COPY`) and whatever additional costs are associated with the extra storage.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from storage costs, there is also a cost associated with requests to S3 bucket. In your case, it will be copy request charges. Please see the detailed pricing categories at
https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Amazon S3 pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/):

```
PUT, COPY, POST, LIST requests: $0.005 per 1,000 requests
```